# Python 3.7: dataclass does not raise `TypeError` for `eq=False`

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

I was trying out the new `dataclasses` in Python 3.7

The `dataclass` decorator can be passed arguments to control the dunder functions that are added to the class.

For some reason, the decorator does not seem to raise `TypeError` for `eq=False` argument.

As per the docs:

```
eq: If true (the default), an __eq__ method will be generated. 
This method compares the class as if it were a tuple of its fields, in order. 
Both instances in the comparison must be of the identical type
```

If I understand correctly, if i pass `eq = False`, `__eq__` function will not be added, and a `TypeError` should be thrown when comparing two instances of the same class. Instead, the `eq` parameter seems to have no effect.

```
@dataclass(eq = False)
class Number:
    val: int

a = Number(1)
b = Number(2)
c = Number(1)

a == b
False

a == c
False
```

The above does not raise `TypeError` and always evaluates to `False`.

```
@dataclass()
class Number:
    val: int

a = Number(1)
b = Number(2)
c = Number(1)

a
Number(val = 1)

a == b
False

a == c
True
```

The other arguments(eg: `order`, `repr`) seem to behave as expected

```
@dataclass(order = False, repr = False)
class Number:
    val:int

a = Number(1)
b = Number(2)
c = Number(1)

a
<__main__.Number object at 0x7fe1036c8b38>

a < b
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                          
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                                       
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Number' and 'Number'
```

Is there some gap in my understanding?

I am using docker image `python/rc-stretch`

Comment: Have you tried `@dataclass(eq = False, order = False)`  to check the first case?

Comment: @RedEyed Just tried. Was still able to do equality check. `TypeError` on < or >.

Comment: Can't reproduce on `python3.7` in so far as once I set `eq = False`, any comparison using `==` always returns `False`. I'll check the docu wether that is the expected behauviour.

Comment: @Arne You're correct. I need to edit the question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In python3.7, given the following dataclass definition

```
@dataclass(eq=False)
class Number:
    val: int
```

the expected result for `Number(1) == Number(1)` is `False`. This is correct since setting `eq = True` only overrides [the default python-object equality function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons), which just checks for identical references (same as `Number(1) is Number(1)`, which might more obviously evaluate to `false`) in this case.

---

The [dataclass specification](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#id7) is a bit lacking here. It explains the `eq` parameter with

> eq: If true (the default), an __eq__ method will be generated. This method compares the class as if it were a tuple of its fields, in order. [...]

but in order to understand the issue you ran into, you also need to know that the basic python object already comes with an `__eq__` function:

```
>>> class A: pass
...
>>> dir(A())
['__class__', '__delattr__', ... '__eq__', ...]  # has __eq__ already
```

Comment: Can you attach a link for the above expected behaviour?

Comment: See [Value comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) in the documentation: "The default behavior for equality comparison (`==` and `!=`) is based on the identity of the objects."

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Good find, I searched for something like that but couldn't quite get it =)

Answer (score 6):

When you don't define `__eq__`, `__eq__` will resolve to `object.__eq__`.  That is what's happening when you create a dataclass with `eq=False`.

`object.__eq__(self, other)` is False unless `self is other`, i.e. unless the two are the same object.